# Check between specific time on weekdays

Tags: php, date, time

How do i make a php which tests if it is between thursday 15:00 and friday 16:00, on any given date.

I am going to use as a check if a specific shipment method should be available on magento 1.8

Comment: minimal working example please

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having this sort of thing hardcoded, you could try something like:

```
$is_valid =
    (date('D') === 'Thu' && date('H') >= 15) ||
    (date('D') === 'Fri' && date('H') < 16);
```

It's a very crude example, but might give you some ideas how to implement. If you don't want it for right now, you can seed the date function with a unix timestamp as the second argument, but it'll get ugly very quickly.

Alternatively, you might get a little more flexibility by using the inbuilt string constructors (if you're going to make the window user-configurable) at a small performance cost

```
$string_to_check = 'now';
$string_start = 'thursday 15:00';
$string_end = 'friday 16:00';

$subject = new \DateTime($string_to_check);
$end = new \DateTimeImmutable($string_end); 
//need to calculate end first for the relative modification
$start = $end->modify(sprintf('previous %s', $string_start));

$is_valid = ($start < $subject && $subject < $end);
```

I can see a limitation that it won't work if the window starts and ends on the same day, although that's easy enough to fix - you can do that if you need to.